# Why did my capacitor explode?

Tags: arduino, capacitor, batteries, motor, motor-controller

I'm new to electronics and am trying to use an Arduino and 2 BTS7960s to control 2 motors. I am powering the circuit with a 20V max Black and Decker battery. Here is what the motor part of the circuit (disregarding the Arduino) looks like:

[image]

The battery wires are attached to a [lever connector](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B08XZJ4SNR). I first plugged in the wires from the BTS7960 to the motors and the lever connector, and then connected the battery wires to the lever connector. A few seconds after doing so, the capacitors on both BTS7960s exploded. I thought some wires might be touching, but I couldn't find any touching wires. The Arduino was off, so there was no reason for power to be drawn from the battery.

Comment: What is a "BTS7960"? You need to give us a link to the manufacturer's datasheet (not a link to the vendor) for that thing. Off the top of my head I would guess that you reversed the polarity of the voltage to the capacitors somehow.

Comment: The pictures on the Internet for the BTS7960 have a different power pinout than what your drawing indicates.

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE! Please draw a schematic. What is the six squares thing in the middle?

Comment: If you did connect the wires like that, the power supply was connected with incorrect polarity, and electrolytic capacitors can explode when connected with incorrect polarity. The big electrolytic capacitors are directly connected to battery input pins. Please double check if this was the reason so it can be made as a formal answer you can accept.

Comment: You need to link to a datasheet for this BTS7960.

Comment: That module also requires 5V DC to operate its logic and drive the power devices. I believe you did not connect the logic ground properly. The motor - and logic ground are connected. Without a schematic I can only guess. Post a schematic, not a frizzy thing to help clarify how you have connected it. The schematic should show all power devices, connections etc. Post links to technical information on the hardware devices.

Comment: How did you test it? with a small load? Verify all supply and return connections that must be clear and common. Take more care with wiring than your schematic suggests when you copy designs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I accidentally reversed the polarity of the wires coming from the battery. Setting them back to normal solved the problem.